# Product flavor specific library dependency in seperate gradle file

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors, android-build-flavors

I need to include product flavor specific libraries. I know that it can be achieved using

```
<productFlavor>Compile(path: "<lib name>", configuration: <productFlavor><buildType>)
```

but is it possible to have product flavor specific gradle files, instead of including all flavor's dependency in a single file.